# "Dynamically bind" variable to another one

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I got a class like this

```
class A {
    this.x
    this.y
}

class B {
    this.x = a.x
    this.y = a.y
}
```

and i would like `b.x` to be 10 when `a.x = 10`, of course, i could do

```
class B {
    set x ( xValue ) {
        a.x = xValue
    }
}
```

But that didn't work with the `+=`, `-=` or whatever other operator

**Context**
I have a `GameObject` class, and, in this class, there is a sprite class, i want that by setting `GameObject.x`, `Sprite.x = GameObject.x`. I could do it in the render function (`func render () => Sprite.x = GameObject.x => render()`) but this is not pragmatic.

I want to stay on the "JS design pattern", so do you know guys how to "bind" `b.x` to `a.x` (like pointers in C for exemple) ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate The question is not opinion-based. You questioning *why* to/not to do something like this is what makes it opinion-based, which was never a part of the original question. The question is, can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: @mhodges The bit at the end seemed like it was asking which should be preferred. I was reading it while running for a train, and evidently I misinterpreted it.

Comment: As to the OP's inquiry, you can achieve a "live link" through a concept called [`prototypal inheritance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), which JavaScript is built on. In fact, it is one of the great things about JavaScript over classical OOP languages.

Comment: Sorry, for the ambiguity, i edited my post

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve a "live link" through a concept called [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), which JavaScript objects are built on. In fact, it is one of the great things about JavaScript over classical OOP languages.

Keep in mind that this approach binds the prototype of the B function object itself, not on the individual instances of B. So, each instance of B will have live links to `a`. These can be overwritten on each individual instance, however, as JavaScript will start on the calling object when looking for properties before traversing up the prototype chain.

```js
function A () {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

function B () {

}
var a = new A();
B.prototype = a;

var b = new B();

a.x += 5;
console.log(b.x);
a.x = 3;
console.log(b.x);
```

Comment: But prototypal inheritance only work with "pure functions" right ? i can't use this method with classes

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt There is no such thing as a true class or classical  inheritance in JavaScript - it always goes back to the prototype chain behind the scenes. IMO, I hate the `class` keyword for that reason; it is ambiguous and very limiting in certain cases.

Comment: Well, so i guess the better way would be to "manualy" bind B.x to A.x  (`B.x = A.x`) when needing B.x ?

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt Yes, but unless `A.x` is an object or an array, you will not get a reference/pointer, you will get a copy of the value.

Comment: @mhodges lovely to meet another who finds JS classes to be a dark pattern.